# how to remove Ubuntu and leave Windows 7 and Linux Mint

Tags: 13.04, windows-7

i have installed Mint Olivia on my computer to run alongside Windows 7 because I thought Ubuntu would automatically be removed, being the computer vegetable that I am. Now I have 3 systems. How can I remove Ubuntu? it is not in program files where Mint is. Thanks in advance for any help.
It starts with Ubuntu showing first then windows 7. when i click on windows seven it gives me the windows or mint option

Comment: In either the Ubuntu system or the Mint system, or while booted from an Ubuntu live CD/DVD/USB, please run the command `sudo parted -l; echo; mount; echo; df -h`. That should show some info about how stuff is installed, and make it possible to give answers with examples that pertain directly to your situation. Then please edit your question to include the output as well a what system you ran the command from. Also, if you can tell, please let us know whether Ubuntu of Linux Mint hosts the currently installed GRUB (i.e., the one that shows the boot menu that lets you select between your OSes).

Comment: Finally, an Ubuntu-based solution to this is possible--for example, [an Ubuntu live CD's *non-chrooted* `grub-install` *can* write the Mint system's GRUB--or any system's GRUB if it's GRUB2--to the MBR](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#via_GRUB2_Rescue_mode). But if you want a Mint-based solution (where the work is done in Mint or a Mint live environment), *then* you should post this somewhere Mint is supported, like [the Mint Forums](http://forums.linuxmint.com/) or [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

To remove Ubuntu (and/or any other Operating System), you can use this little tool: [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller).

[image]